# Getting Contents of Google form on Email after a user submits a google form

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get the contents of the google form sent to my email rather than just a notification that a new user has submitted the form. I put in the following code. But I get a response saying that namedValues is undefined. I tried actually submitting a dummy google form, but it still doesn't send me the contents of the google form on email. 
function sendFormByEmail (e) {
     var email = "example@gmail.com";

```
 var Name = e.values[3]; 
 var EmailAddress = e.values[4];
 var txt = ""; 
 for(var field in e.namedValues) {
 txt += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
 }
 MailApp.sendEmail(email, "New Client", txt); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the script is attached to the form and triggered when that form is submitted, use the [response object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) with that event.  AFAIK the namedValues object you are trying to access is only available if your script is attached to the spreadsheet that recieves the form input.

I use this script when I want to quickly send a simple form submission to an email address (and not use the addons that can do this and more):

```
function onFormSubmit_sendEmail(e) {
  var msgBody = "";
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    msgBody = msgBody + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + ": " + itemResponse.getResponse() + "\n\n";
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail("someemail@somedomain", "Form Submission", msgBody); 
  }
}
```

You can use some tests on the item title ([getTitle() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#gettitle)) to do different things depending on the question - e.g. if one question is where you want the email sent to, do something like:

```
if (itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() == "Recipient Address") {
  var email = itemResponse.getResponse();
```

You could then use that MailApp.sendMail() function. Hope this helps.